# how to handle Dropdownlist in Laravel

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu

In My Blade I have a Dropdownlist with a name="user_selected" which is connected with a table as follows:
table name is earnmilescodes has 2 fields codevalue and bookingcode.

```html
<div class="col-75">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectcode" name="user_selected" required focus>
        <option value="" disabled selected>--- Select Destination ---</option>
        @foreach ($earnmilescodes as $earnmilescodes)
            <option value="{{$earnmilescodes->codevalue}}">{{$earnmilescodes->bookingcode}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select> 
</div>
```

I would like to save both `$earnmilescodes->codevalue` and `$earnmilescodes->bookingcode` to mysql in a table called (Flown).

I am able to save `$earnmilescodes->codevalue` to mysql by using `$request->input('user_selected');` as you can see below.

but I don't know how to refer to `$earnmilescodes->bookingcode`.

my Controller is as follows

```php
$newflown = new Flown();
$newflown->earnmilescode=$request->input('user_selected'); // this is fine
$newflown->earnmilesvalue=$request->???????????;           // what to put after $request-> ?
```

I hope my question is clear and if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your `earnmilescodes` is structured as follows

```
+-----------+
|id (pk)    |
|codevalue  |
|bookingcode|
+-----------+
```

Or it has no `id` field and `codevalue` acts as the pk.

In any case, what you should do is having the pk as the select's value and then do a select query in your controller.

```php
$newflown = new Flown(); 
$earnmilescode = EarnMilesCode::where('codevalue', $request->input('user_selected'))->firstOrFail();
// Or $earnmilescode = EarnMilesCode::findOrFail($request->input('user_selected')) if codevalue is the pk

$newflown->earnmilescode  = $earnmilescode->bookingcode;
$newflown->earnmilesvalue = $earnmilescode->codevalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In you blade you can set both booking code and booking value by concatenating both by some character like

<option value="{{$earnmilescodes->codevalue. '*****' .$earnmilescodes->bookingcode}}">{{$earnmilescodes->bookingcode}}</option>

and in you controller just explode selected value and use it like 

$earnmilescode = explode('*****',$request->input('user_selected'))[1];
$earnmilesvalue = explode('*****',$request->input('user_selected'))[0]; 

$newflown = new Flown();
$newflown->earnmilescode= $earnmilescode;
$newflown->earnmilesvalue= $earnmilesvalue;
```